# Fork two child process, one to compute sum of N and the other the factorial of N

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have to take an integer argument from the command line. Create two child processes. The first computes the sum of positive integers and the second the factorial. The parent must also wait for each child to finish, then the parent prints out "done" with its own identifier.

an output example is

```
[ID = 101] Sum of positive integers up to 5 is 15
[ID = 102] Factorial of 5 is 120
[ID = 100] Done
```

but the output I am getting is

```
 [ ID = 4262] Factorial of 5 is 120
[ID = 4262] DONE
[ID = 4260] DONE
[ ID = 4261] sum of positive integers up to 5 is 15
```

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
pid_t ret;
int i, num,sum=0,fact=1;

ret=fork();
    for(i=1;i<argc; i++){
        num=atoi(argv[1]);

    }
if (ret == 0) {
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    sum+=i;
    }
    printf("\n [ ID = %d] sum of positive integers up to %d is %d\n",getpid(),num,sum);
}

else{
    if(fork()==0){
    for(i=1;i<=num; i++){
        fact*=i;    
    }printf("\n [ ID = %d] Factorial of %d is %d\n",getpid(),num,fact);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("\n[ID = %d] DONE",getpid());
}

return 0;
}
```

My problem is that i'm not sure how to properly fork to have 2 child processes.

Comment: If you write to the error stream instead, are the results different? The error stream is normally unbuffered.

Comment: Your code would be a *lot* simpler to understand if you used functions to do the work instead of all inline inside `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you first to create two separate functions, `sum()` and `fact()` that implement the tasks each respective child process should perform:

```
void sum(int num) { /* ... */ }
void fact(int num) { /* ... */ }
```

Then, have pointer functions referring to those functions:

```
typedef (*child_task_t)(int);

child_task_t child_task[2];
child_task[0] = sum;
child_task[1] = fact;
```

That way, you can easily `fork()` to have two children by means of a `for`-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   switch(fork()) {
   case 0: // parent
      continue;
   case -1: // error
      return -1;
   default: // child
      task_child[i](num); // <-- run the task
      exit(0); // child process finishes
   }
}

// parent waits for the children to finish
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   wait(NULL);
```

Comment: and don't forget to `wait()` for *all* of the children.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks!

Comment: you also need to ensure that each child does actually explicitly `exit()`  (or `return` after the call to `task_child`) otherwise the child processes' flow of execution will continue after the `switch`.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks, better to explicitly call `exit()` in the `switch` than relying on the task functions having a call to `exit()`.

Comment: probably, yes.  The `return` is only OK if you're in `main` where it's equivalent to an implicit exit.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in your code, I commented it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pid_t ret;
    int i, num,sum=0,fact=1;

    ret=fork();
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        num = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    if (ret == 0) 
    {
        /* in first child */
        for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
            sum+=i;
        }
        printf("\n [ ID = %d] sum of positive integers up to %d is %d\n",getpid(),num,sum);
        /* here, you should exit from first child 
           with exit or return */

    }
    else
    {
        /* here, we are in parent */
        if(fork()==0)
        {
            /* here, in second child */
            for(i=1;i<=num; i++){
                fact*=i;    
            }
            printf("\n [ ID = %d] Factorial of %d is %d\n",getpid(),num,fact);
            /* here, you should exit from second child 
                with exit or return */

        }

        /* warning, second child and parent get there */
        /* warning, here you only wait for one child */
        wait(NULL);
        printf("\n[ID = %d] DONE",getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's quite easy to simplify it:

- isolate childs' code
- identify which line will be executed by parent or child
- wait for childs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pid_t ret;
    int i, num,sum=0,fact=1;

    /* get parameter (you should test the value of argc before) */
    num = atoi(argv[1]);    

    /* create a first child */
    if (0 == fork()) 
    {
        /* in first child */
        for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
            sum+=i;
        }
        printf("\n [ ID = %d] sum of positive integers up to %d is %d\n",getpid(),num,sum);

        /* exit from first child */
        exit(0);    
    }

    /* this point will not be reached by first child */

    /* create a second child */
    if ( 0 == fork())
    {
        /* here, in second child */
        for(i=1;i<=num; i++){
            fact*=i;    
        }
        printf("\n [ ID = %d] Factorial of %d is %d\n",getpid(),num,fact);
        /* exit from second child */
        exit(0);           
    }

    /* this point will not be reached by second child */

    /* wait for one child */
    wait(NULL);

    /* wait for a second child */
    wait(NULL);

    printf("\n[ID = %d] DONE",getpid());

    return 0;
}
```